# BizTalk Health Monitor

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, bhm

I'm trying to run the "Analyze Now" on BHM50.exe (BizTalk Health Monitor) on BizTalk 2016.
I opened as Administrator, and I should have all the necessary privileges.

We have two BizTalk servers in a group, with SQL on a different machine.

It gives this error.

> Launching "D:\Program Files (x86)\BizTalkHealthMonitor\BHMCOLLECT.EXE"
> -PROFILE:C:\PROGRA~3\MICROS~1\BIZTAL~2\MBVSET~1.XML
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'MYHC, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=fa6906311f4bb5cd' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at
> MyHealthCheck.Class1.Init(String[] args)

There were no matches at all on Google for this error.

Sample screen shot:

[image]

It's complaining about MyHC - does it need to be put in the GAC?
Here it is in the same directory where I installed the utility.
[image]

Comment: Uninstall, re-install of BHM usually fixes these sort of issues

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thanks, I reinstalled on the C Drive instead of the D Drive, and that seems to have resolved it.  We have BizTalk itself on the D:\Program Files (x86), so I originally I installed in that directory.  I might try D drive again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error when one of the BHM components is not "compatible" with the others. This issue can occur during a partial self-update of BHM.
When you update BHM using its self-update features, be sure that all the components proposed in the update were well downloaded; if only a part of them is downloaded in the BHM folder, you will have this kind of error at the BHM startup or collect start.
If you redownload and reinstall BHM, you should not meet this error but you will have to self-update BHM to have its latest components downloaded (queries/rules repository, collect engine, MMC snapin, etc...)

JP (BHM Dev team)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the latest version. There is an option for that RC/BHM Update